# Difference b/w putting condition in JOIN clause versus WHERE clause

Tags: sql, inner-join

Suppose I have 3 tables.

#### Sales Rep

- Rep Code
- First Name
- Last Name
- Phone
- Email
- Sales Team

#### Orders

- Order Number
- Rep Code
- Customer Number
- Order Date
- Order Status

#### Customer

- Customer Number
- Name
- Address
- Phone Number

I want to get a detailed report of Sales for 2010. I would be doing a join. I am interested in knowing which of the following is more efficient and why ?

```
SELECT 
    O.OrderNum, R.Name, C.Name
FROM
    Order O INNER JOIN Rep R ON O.RepCode = R.RepCode
            INNER JOIN Customer C ON O.CustomerNumber = C.CustomerNumber
WHERE
    O.OrderDate >= '01/01/2010'
```

#### OR

```
SELECT 
    O.OrderNum, R.Name, C.Name
FROM
    Order O INNER JOIN Rep R ON (O.RepCode = R.RepCode AND O.OrderDate >= '01/01/2010')
            INNER JOIN Customer C ON O.CustomerNumber = C.CustomerNumber
```

Answer (score 4):

JOINs must reflect the relationship aspect of your tables.  WHERE clause, is a place where you filter records.  I prefer the first one.

Make it readable first, table relationships should be obvious (by using JOINs), then profile

Efficiency-wise, the only way to know is to profile it, different database have different planner on executing the query

Wherein some database might apply filter first, then do the join subsquently; some database might join tables blindly first, then execute where clause later.  Try to profile, on Postgres and MySQL use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, in SQL Server use Ctrl+K, with SQL Server you can see which of the two queries is faster relative to each other

Comment: +1. Queries become more difficult to read once the WHERE clause starts getting cluttered with a bunch of conditions.

Comment: +1 - ...and, you're not going to know how the SQL parser is going to construct the query until you do an "explain plan," so the harder-to-read version may not even result in any advantage. If there's a performance problem with the easy-to-read version, you could tweak it, but I wouldn't do anything without the empirical evidence your database system can provide.